# Typescript Generics: return instance of class parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a data store and want to create a method to load data from the store.
The store contains different types (classes) of data.
Let's say my store contains (among other) data of type Author.
I want to load author with id 1:

```
const author1 = store.loadById(Author, 1);
```

Now how do I have to use generics to get the TS compiler know that author1 is an instance of Author?

I now have

```
public loadById<T>(entityClass: T, id: number): T {
        const entity;
        // logic to load the entity ...
        return entity;
    }
```

but that is wrong because now the TSC thinks my method returns a entityClass rather than an instance of the entityClass.
So how do I have to specify the return type of the method to get author1 to be an instance of Author?

Comment: Do you actually need the class in the method? If not, `loadById<Author>(1)` supplies the generic type. Otherwise, I think you want `typeof T`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `typeof` will not work on a generic parameter.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir ah, thanks; I'd respond that you need a `new` signature, then, but you've already written that answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are passing in the class `Author` to the method, not an instance of the `Author` class, so the parameter needs to be a constructor signature:

```
public loadById<T>(entityClass: new () => T, id: number): T {
    const entity = new entityClass();
    // logic to load the entity ...
    return entity;
}
const author1 = store.loadById(Author, 1); // will be of type Author
```

Or if you have argument to the constructor, you can specify those in the signature:

```
public loadById<T>(entityClass: new (data: any) => T, id: number): T {
    const entity = new entityClass(null as any); // pass data
    // logic to load the entity ...
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! Could you please add an example of how I should call the loadById method in the last case (with data)? And how is the data passed to the entityClass instance? Now the code is ```(null as any)```. How do I get the data inside loadById?

Comment: @mvermand how you get the data is something that depends on what you are doing and I can't comment on it. Once you have some data in a variable, you can just call `entityClass` as you would any other constructor `new entityClass(data)`

Answer (score 5):

For those who want to pass a class and return an instance of the class

```
function newInstance<T extends new () => InstanceType<T>>(TheClass: T): InstanceType<T> {
    return new TheClass();
}
```

Comment: This works perfect for classes, but not for "literal" functions. Why?
For instance, `newInstance(function xyz() {})` and `newInstance(function () {})`, I get `Type '() => void' provides no match for the signature 'new (): any'`