# Signature for generic function that returns an instance of the (possibly abstract) class it's passed

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Basically, I'm trying to type `getA()` in the following (drastically simplified) code:

```js
interface Base {
  readonly id: string
}

class Foo implements Base {
    get id() {return 'a foo'}
    get ping() {return 'pong'}
}

abstract class Bee {
    abstract get bing(): string
}

class Bar implements Base, Bee { 
    get id() {return 'a bar'}
    get bing() {return 'Crosby'}
}

class Baz implements Base, Bee {    
    get id() {return 'a bar'}
    get bing() {return 'cherry'}
}

function getA(type, name) {
    // Some dynamic lookup happens here
    if (type === Foo) {
        return new Foo()
    } else if (type === Bee && name === 'bar') {
        return new Bar()
    } else if (type === Bee && name === 'baz') {
        return new Baz()
    } else {
        throw new Error('unknown args')
    }
}

console.log(getA(Foo, 'foo').ping)
console.log(getA(Bee, 'bar').bing)
```

This is [doable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50851045/typescript-generics-return-instance-of-class-parameter) (though awkward) without the abstract classes:

```js
function getA<T extends Base>(type: {new(): T}, name: string): T
```

but abstract classes don’t have constructors (for obvious reasons) and I can’t seem to find any other way to refer to the type (rather than an instance of it). I’m also open to suggestions of possible refactors if there might be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Abstract classes do have constructors, you just aren't allowed to call them in TypeScript.  You just need to use an [abstract construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#computed-and-constant-members) of the form `abstract new(...)=>...` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYvZ3w).  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing? (I also don't understand why you want to call `getA(Bee, "baz")` instead of `getA(Baz)`, but since your code is "drastically simplified" I assume there's something motivating that in the full code.)

Comment: @Wolfgang class mapping + function overload: Does this work for you? https://tsplay.dev/W48x7W

Comment: @jcalz `abstract new` turns out to be exactly what I was looking for; in fact I think I had tried it at one point but encountered a different problem and got myself tangled up—the types in the actual code are currently rather confused and need cleaning up. (Regarding `getA(Bee, "baz")`: the actual implementation involves a dynamic lookup on `name`, which will figure out what the type and constructor arguments are for that specific ID. But sometimes the code knows what abstract class it wants and doesn't care about the specific subtype.)

Comment: @jsejcksn I think your implementation is a little too specialized to my example; the function body was simply intended to illustrate that we may get different types based on the string parameter. In practice finding the actual type that will be returned involves a database lookup and so can't be known at compile time.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer although it's getting to be bedtime in jcalzland so it might be a little while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [abstract constructor type expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures) which looks just like a normal "concrete" constructor type expression*, except you write `abstract new` instead of just `new`:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
}
type FooCtor = new (a: string) => Foo;
type AbstractFooCtor = abstract new (a: string) => Foo;
```

If you have a concrete constructor you can `new` it:

```
declare let ConcreteFoo: FooCtor;
new ConcreteFoo("yes"); // okay
```

But you can't do that with an abstract constructor:

```
let AbstractFoo: AbstractFooCtor;
new AbstractFoo("no"); // error, cannot create an instance of an abstract class
```

Note that abstract constructors are considered a proper supertype of concrete constructors, so you can use a concrete constructor in place of an abstract one, but not vice versa:

```
AbstractFoo = ConcreteFoo; // okay, concrete ctor is a subtype of abstract ctor
ConcreteFoo = AbstractFoo; // error, abstract ctor is not a subtype of concrete ctor
```

---

Anyway, that means you can write `getA()`'s call signature like

```
function getA(type: abstract new () => any, name: string) {/*...*/}
// or whatever arg/ret you want  ^^^^^^^^^
```

and everything should work.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJwBcyAzmFKAOYDcuAvrmAJ4AOKG6AwmOlMgF5kICAHdkACmJkK1AJSCAfGkx0W7ZAEEARuSiIwnHn0GFdFA8LGTpe+UpXo6uACYQEAGzhQUHiGGQudBAEH0hOEiNeKDoRcSCQsIhOCQAiZghSVLkaZAB6POR0AGs4ZlxcPwCdPQMIrXN9BENMYxjcOIba5pTUkHRs3ILkaCg+ABpkBDgQfoDQiDhIQhBkUHIZpCKYFbNu+a9SUgqaix7MUwSF8NV8wpKyyYRg65Rmk2BSQjIAV211FDoHZwRqWd5QXBXJKcUynJotJx3EZQMZQSYg-ZTaJrL5zb6kP4A7ZTF5JLF8Cq4UCQWCIFAAITgpBQeAIPjgLmCHmYaxcJDsICoDAqniZXxhwAAtqw-JKIOAvozmTh8MgqP5eRIFNhkGEflBVgByODIGCYQ3IRgEdUBVjULU4XX+fVG1jBKgWxiMXAYs4HMXIekQFmq33wtUa7T2uT82SC4W4UVHQPeNbS2XysCKpkQSZBkPWjXAFwOnV6g3IY3IbTeT2qm3V6OO8tGrhjUjaZh171J7MALzTMogcoVKeZeeDKsLAWLpadYBdlZNNagdenjcFc5blYQAAtRl3LQmYD8QmBgMEI2BNBIASQw5ZOg6BMoZsxJiA4HLY5RBdrVcAOy3mwKACGBjj-gQbLOhWnQpHIqr0CMHjKoBkhEmBQj5sgABkOHCF+oHgYaK6GpBUHbp0jJQFqiHIahQEYeB2F4QRcqCMRNZ9mRU4UTBqxUXAfa0QQSEQChBZQWAu5jOInQAKIonwEiGqexT9KIqzeFQpBkYhwpAA)

<sup>*The TS documentation refers to [construct *signatures*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) and [abstract construct *signatures*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures) instead of constructor *type expressions*, but this is a bit ambiguous or incorrect. A call/construct *signature* looks like `{ (arg: Arg): Ret }` or `{ new (arg: Arg): Ret }` whereas a function/constructor [*type expression*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) looks like `(arg: Arg) => Ret` or `new (arg: Arg) => Ret`.  This difference matters here, because while `abstract new (arg: Arg) => Ret` is valid TypeScript syntax since TS4.2, the potentially equivalent `{ abstract new (arg: Arg): Ret }` is *invalid* syntax. Hence my terminology above.</sup>